limit involving the ratio of two exponential functions: Taylor vs Laurent series
I have been trying to verify a result which is given as if self-evident in eq. 8 in this book. Slightly rephrased, it reads:
$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \left[\frac{n}{x^2}-\frac{nt_0^2e^{-t_0x}}{\left(1-e^{-t_0x}\right)^2}\right]=\frac{nt_0^2}{12} $$
where $n$ and $t_0$ are just non-zero, given constants. I seem unable to replicate this result. The main problem, as I understand it, is finding the following limit, which features the ratio between two functions involving exponentials:
$$
 \lim_{x \to 0} \left[\frac{t_0^2e^{-t_0x}}{\left(1-e^{-t_0x}\right)^2} \right]
$$
My least frustrating attempt so far has been to approximate both numerator $g(x)=t_0^2e^{-t_0x}$ and denominator $f(x)=\left(1-e^{-t_0x}\right)^2$ by Taylor (Maclaurin) expansion about zero, based on the following derivatives:

Denominator $f(x)$:
$f'(x)=2t_0e^{-t_0x}\left(e^{-t_ox}-1\right)$
$f''(x)=2t_0^2e^{-t_0x}\left(1-2e^{-t_0x}\right) $
$f'''(x)=2t_0^3e^{-t_0x}\left(4e^{-t_0x}-1\right)$
$...$

Numerator $g(x)$:
$g'(x) = -t_0^3e^{-t_0x} $
$g''(x) = t_0^4e^{-t_0x}$
$g'''(x) = -t_0^5e^{-t_0x}$
$...$


Considering only the first few terms of the Taylor series, I obtain the ratio:
\begin{align}
 \lim_{x \to 0} \left[\frac{t_0^2e^{-t_0x}}{\left(1-e^{-t_0x}\right)^2} \right] &= \lim_{x \to 0} \left[\frac{t_0^2 - xt_0^3+\frac{x^2}{2!}t_0^3+\mathcal{O}\left(x^3\right)}{-\frac{x^2}{2!}2t_0+\mathcal{O}\left(x^3\right)} \right]\\
 &= \lim_{x \to 0} \left[ -\frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{t_0}{x} - \frac{t_0^2}{2} \right] \\ 
 & = -\frac{t_0^2}{2} 
\end{align}
whereas I was hoping for $-\frac{t_0^2}{12}$ instead. Even including a third term leads me to the same result.
If I try and verify using e.g. Wolfram Alpha it suggests a Laurent series expansion at zero, the first two terms of which are exactly what I am after i.e. $\left[\frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{t_0^2}{12}\right] $. Yet I have no formal background in complex analysis hence it's a bit tricky for me to work out how Wolfram Alpha's solution comes about, and how that's different from the Taylor expansion I've attempted in the first place.
UPDATE: following this very useful hint in the comments, I have set $y=t_0x$ and re-stated the problem as follows:
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0} \left[ \frac{n}{\left(y / t_0\right)^2} -nt_0^2 \frac{e^{-y}}{\left( 1-e^{-y} \right)^2} \right] &= nt_0^2 \left\{ \lim_{x \to 0} \left[ \frac{1}{y^2} - \frac{e^{-y}}{\left( 1-e^{-y}\right)^2} \right] \right\} \\
&= nt_0^2 \left\{  \lim_{x \to 0} \left[  \frac{\left(1-e^{-y}\right)^2 - y^2e^{-y}}{\left(1-e^{-y}\right)^2} \right] \right\} \\
& = nt_0^2 \left\{  \lim_{x \to 0} \left[  \frac{\left(\frac{1-e^{-y}}{y}\right)^2-e^{-y}}{\left(1-e^{-y}\right)^2}\right]  \right\}
\end{align}
Once again, I seek to approximate $f(x)=e^{-y}$ and $g(x)=\left( 1-e^{-y}\right)^2$ by Taylor expansion about zero, which yields:
$$
\left(1-e^{-y}\right)^2=\frac{y^2}{2!}2-\frac{y^3}{3!}6+\frac{y^4}{4!}14-\frac{y^5}{5!}30+\frac{y^6}{6!}62-\frac{y^7}{7!}126+\mathcal{O}\left(x^8\right)
$$
and
\begin{align}
 \frac{\left(1-e^{-y}\right)^2}{y^2}-e^{-y} &=
1-\frac{y}{3!}6+\frac{y^2}{4!}14-\frac{y^3}{5!}30+\frac{y^4}{6!}62-\frac{y^5}{7!}126+...-1+y-\frac{y^2}{2!}+\frac{y^3}{3!}-\frac{y^4}{4!}+\frac{y^5}{5!}+... \\
&= \left(1-\frac{6}{3!}\right)y+\left(\frac{14}{4!}-\frac{1}{2!}\right)y^2+\left(\frac{1}{3!}-\frac{30}{5!}\right)y^3+\left(\frac{62}{6!}-\frac{1}{4!}\right)y^4+\left(\frac{1}{5!}-\frac{126}{7!}\right)y^5 +... \\
& = \frac{1}{12}y^2-\frac{1}{12}y^3+\frac{2}{45}y^5-\frac{1}{60}y^5+...
\end{align}
which can then be combined as:
\begin{align}
nt_0^2 \left\{  \lim_{x \to 0} \left[  \frac{\left(\frac{1-e^{-y}}{y}\right)^2-e^{-y}}{\left(1-e^{-y}\right)^2}\right]  \right\}  & =  nt_0^2 \left\{ \lim_{x \to 0}  \left[  \frac{\frac{1}{12}y^2-\frac{1}{12}y^3+\frac{2}{45}y^5-\frac{1}{60}y^5+...}{y^2-y^3+\frac{7}{12}y^4-\frac{1}{4}y^5+...} \right]\right\} \\
&=nt_0^2 \left\{ \lim_{x \to 0} \left[ \frac{1}{12}\frac{y^2}{y^2} + \frac{1}{12}\frac{y^3}{y^3} + \frac{8}{105}\frac{y^4}{y^4} + \frac{1}{15}\frac{y^5}{y^5} +... \right] \right\} \\
&=\frac{nt_0^2}{12}+...
\end{align}
The above is just meant to build on the insightful comments received, and to check if my understanding of the hints provided is correct - hopefully I haven't made additional mistakes in the process.

Pull out $nt_0^2$ and substitute $y=-t_0x.$ The expression simplifies

My apologies @RyszardSzwarc but even with the suggested simplification I end up in a  similar spot. Specifically: $\lim_{y \to 0}\left[t_0^2\frac{e^y}{\left(1-e^y\right)^2}\right]=\lim_{y \to 0}\left[t_0^2\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{y^k}{k!} }{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{y^k}{k!}2 \left(1-2^{k-1}\right)  }\right]$. Considering up to the fourth derivatives in the expansion I seem to get $-\frac{t_0^2}{2}$, surely I am missing something?

On substitution you will get $nt_0^2$ times $$\lim_{y\to 0}\left [{1\over y^2}-{e^y\over (1-e^y)^2}\right ]$$

In order to calculate your limit, I will use the following notables limits:
$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{e^x-1}x=1\qquad\color{blue}{(1)}$
$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}=\dfrac12\qquad\color{blue}{(2)}$
$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{e^x-1-x-\frac{x^2}2}{x^3}=\dfrac16\qquad\color{blue}{(3)}$
Now, I am going to calculate your limit:
$\lim\limits_{y\to0}\left[\dfrac1{y^2}-\dfrac{e^y}{(1-e^y)^2}\right]=\lim\limits_{y\to0}\left[\dfrac1{y^2}-\dfrac{e^y}{(e^y-1)^2}\right]=$
$=\lim\limits_{y\to0}\left(\!\dfrac y{e^y-1}\!\right)^{\!2}\!\left[\dfrac{(e^y-1)^2}{y^4}-\dfrac{e^y}{y^2}\right]=$
$=\lim\limits_{y\to0}\left(\!\dfrac y{e^y-1}\!\right)^{\!2}\!\left[\dfrac{(e^y-1)^2-y^2e^y}{y^4}\right]=$
$=\lim\limits_{y\to0}\left(\!\dfrac y{e^y-1}\!\right)^{\!2}\!\left(\!\dfrac{e^y-1+ye^{\frac y2}}y\!\right)\!\left(\!\dfrac{e^y-1-ye^{\frac y2}}{y^3}\!\right).$
On the other hand, it results that
$\lim\limits_{y\to0}\left(\!\dfrac y{e^y-1}\!\right)^{\!2}\overset{\color{blue}{(1)}}{=}1^2=1\;\;\;,$
$\lim\limits_{y\to0}\dfrac{e^y-1+ye^{\frac y2}}y=\lim\limits_{y\to0}\left(\!\dfrac{e^y-1}y+e^{\frac y2}\!\right)\overset{\color{blue}{(1)}}{=}1+1=2\;\;\;,$
$\lim\limits_{y\to0}\dfrac{e^y\!-\!1\!-\!ye^{\frac y2}}{y^3}=\lim\limits_{y\to0}\dfrac{e^y\!-\!1\!-\!y\!-\!\frac{y^2}2\!-\!y\left(e^{\frac y2}\!-1\!-\!\frac y2\right)}{y^3}=$
$=\lim\limits_{y\to0}\left[\dfrac{e^y\!-\!1\!-\!y\!-\!\frac{y^2}2}{y^3}-\dfrac14\dfrac{e^{\frac y2}\!-1\!-\!\frac y2}{\left(\frac y2\right)^2}\right]\underset{\overbrace{\text{ by letting }\;z=\frac y2\;}}{=}$
$=\lim\limits_{y\to0}\dfrac{e^y\!-\!1\!-\!y\!-\!\frac{y^2}2}{y^3}-\dfrac14\lim\limits_{z\to0}\dfrac{e^z\!-1\!-\!z}{z^2}\underset{\overbrace{\color{blue}{(3)}\text{ and }\color{blue}{(2)}}}{=}$
$=\dfrac16-\dfrac14\!\cdot\!\dfrac12=\dfrac16-\dfrac18=\dfrac1{24}\,.$
Consequently, we get that
$\lim\limits_{y\to0}\left[\dfrac1{y^2}-\dfrac{e^y}{(1-e^y)^2}\right]=$
$=\lim\limits_{y\to0}\left(\!\dfrac y{e^y-1}\!\right)^{\!2}\!\left(\!\dfrac{e^y-1+ye^{\frac y2}}y\!\right)\!\left(\!\dfrac{e^y-1-ye^{\frac y2}}{y^3}\!\right)=$
$=1\!\cdot\!2\!\cdot\!\dfrac1{24}=\dfrac1{12}\,.$

This was very helpful, I must admit I wasn't aware of those notable limits - thank you for bringing those identities us, and for working this out explicitly, it's been very informative

@DrEti, you are welcome.
